# Android: Search Dialog doesn't appear

Tags: java, android, xml, search, android-manifest

I'm currently trying to implement a Search in my App. I followed [Google's Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) but now, when i press the "Search"-Button (on the Device/Emulator), nothing appears. I'm not sure why.

My searchable.xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/label_search"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:includeInGlobalSearch="true"
  >

</searchable>
```

This is the Android Manifest part for the Search-Activity:

```
 <!-- Search Activity -->
 <activity android:name=".SearchNotes">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
 </activity>
```

The Code which populates my ListActivity:

```
private void searchAndDisplay(String query){
    SQLiteDatabase db = db_con.getReadableDatabase();
    final Cursor c = db.rawQuery(
            "SELECT headline, id as '_id' FROM entry WHERE " +
            "(headline LIKE '%?%') OR (content LIKE '%?%') ",
            new String[]{query, query});
    this.startManagingCursor(c);
    final ListAdapter searchAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, c, 
            new String[] {"headline", "_id"}, 
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
    this.setListAdapter(searchAdapter);
    db.close();
}
```

This doesn't work in the Emulator, neither on my Android-Device.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you post your code for SearchDialog or SearchView part?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. I edited my Post with the Method which populates my ListActivity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have

```
<activity android:name=".OtherActivity" ... >
    <!-- enable the search dialog to send searches to SearchableActivity -->
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
               android:value=".SearchNotes" />
</activity>
```

inside your Activity tag? It can also be applied to the Application if you so choose.

Comment: SearchNotes is the Activity that should display the found items. In my Android Manifest i have only what i posted on the SearchNotes-Activity. But giving it the "value"-Attribute changes nothing.

Comment: Then put the meta-data in your application tag. <application><activity/><meta-data/><application/>

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid if `android:includeInGlobalSearch="true"` is causing an issue, since it requires below steps to be implemented. Try removing `android:includeInGlobalSearch="true"` from `searchable.xml` and see if it helps

To provide recent queries suggestions, you need to:

- Implement a searchable activity, as described in Creating a Search Interface.
- Create a content provider that extends SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider and declare it in your application manifest.
- Modify the searchable configuration with information about the content provider that provides search suggestions.
- Save queries to your content provider each time a search is executed.

Ref: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-recent-query-suggestions.html

Answer (score -1):

Everything appears fine in your code. What you need to do is just after running your application you should click the *Menu* button in your emulator or on your mobile. This will open the search option. Choose that and you should be able to search.